# Prove the linear of differential system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

we have the system, $$g_i(x,u) = a_{i1}(x)u_1 + a_{i2}(x)u_2 +\cdots+a_{in}(x)u_n + b_i(x), \; 1\leq i \leq n$$
then, it can be written as $$u' = A(x)u + b(x)$$

where $A(x)$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with elements $a_{ij} (x)$; $b(x)$ is an $n\times 1$ vector with components $b_i(x)$, and $u(x)$ is an $n\times 1$ unknown vector with components $u_i(x)$.

The question is if we change the independent variable $x = p(t)$. Is the system still remain linear ?

The way I approach this problem is I rewrote the system above into the form: 
$$r_i(x) = a_{i1}(x)y + a_{i2}(x)\frac{dy}{dx} +...+a_{in}(x)\frac{d^ny}{dx} + b_i(x)$$
then, if we change the the independent variable $x = p(t)$, the linear system will become 
$$r_i(p(t)) = a_{i1}y(p(t)) a_{i2}\frac{dy}{dt}p'(t)+ ... + a_{i}{n}\sum_{n=0}^{k}p_{kn}\frac{d^ny}{dt}$$
So, this system will still remain linear. Is this approach correct ?

Comment: If you change the independent variable, then the linearity of the system is not affected at all. The coefficients of course change.

Comment: I know it will not be affected at all. But, how can I prove it is linear after changing it. Moreover, I don't know if my thinking is the right or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your substitution makes no sense. While one routinely reduces higher order ODE to first order systems, the other direction does not work, at least not in this way.

Set $v(t)=u(p(t))$ and thus $v'(t)=u'(p(t))p'(t)$ by the rule of Alexandre Chain and use the fact that a reparametrization is, usually, a diffeomorphism, to find the modified system of equations.

Comment: if I set like you said above, the system will become $$r_i(t) = a_{i1}v(t) + a_{i2}v'(t)+...+a_{in}v^n(t)$$. Is it correct ?

Comment: No, your goal is a system $v'(t)=C(t)v(t)+d(t)$ where $C$ relates coefficient wise to $A$ and $d$ to $b$.

Comment: oh, I know what you mean. Thank you